# Video playback from laptop to external screen causes stutter

Tags: video-playback

I have created a video for a presentation. It's an AVI with lossless H.264 encoding. It plays from my laptop on a 2560x1440 screen at 60 Hz. Every now and then it stutters.

Is there a straightforward way to fix the stuttering? I will try lowering the quality. Can a different codec solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VGA or HDMI to play it on the external screen? Try the follwing:

- Download and install k-lite mega codec (Choose Mega from the list) from here: https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm , choose simple installation and dont change the default values. After installing, go the the video file, right click and select open with>MPC HC.Check if your issue is solved
- When you connect VGA/HDMI, on the laptop select to display on second screen only:for this if you are using windows 10, press windows key + A, then in the notification/action center click on "project" and then "select second screen only"

Comment: I'm using DisplayPort connection.

Comment: @LarsMelander did you try the klite mega codec pack+Media payer classic ??

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately it didn't work. I've found a different solution, but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works in this case: using Windows Media Player with a RAM disk. Dunno why, but it's the best solution I found.